# What is the criteria for light weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

So when I was researching a stealth-based ninja I came across weapon finesse and piranha strike which mention light weapons. I know there's the light weapon property but what would the criteria for light weapons be assuming their not on the SRD but exist in IRL.

> You are trained in using your agility in melee combat, as opposed to
>   brute strength.
>
> Benefit: With a light weapon, elven curve blade, rapier, whip, or
>   spiked chain made for a creature of your size category, you may use
>   your Dexterity modifier instead of your Strength modifier on attack
>   rolls. If you carry a shield, its armor check penalty applies to your
>   attack rolls.
>
> Special: Natural weapons are considered light weapons.
>
> Editor’s Note

> You make a combination of quick strikes, sacrificing accuracy for
>   multiple, minor wounds that prove exceptionally deadly.
>
> Prerequisites: Weapon Finesse, base attack bonus +1.
>
> Benefit: When wielding a light weapon, you can choose to take a -1
>   penalty on all melee attack rolls and combat maneuver checks to gain a
>   +2 bonus on all melee damage rolls. This bonus to damage is halved (-50%) if you are making an attack with an off-hand weapon or
>   secondary natural weapon. When your base attack bonus reaches +4, and
>   for every 4 points thereafter, the penalty increases by -1 and the
>   bonus on damage rolls increases by +2. You must choose to use this
>   feat before the attack roll, and its effects last until your next
>   turn. The bonus damage does not apply to touch attacks or effects that
>   do not deal hit point damage. This feat cannot be used in conjunction
>   with the Power Attack feat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Paizo has never published any. They assign the light property when they feel it is appropriate, and almost-certainly do not even internally have any hard-and-fast rule for it. The criteria for being a light weapon is that the author assigned the “light” property to it, and that’s it.